# escapeshellarg() on urlencoded data

Tags: php

I sent $data (array) from one server to another as shown below.  When it gets to the second server, the $data elements are obviously urlencoded.  On the second server, I wish to use some of the $data in exec().  Even though I pass a hash and make sure it is valid on the other end, I would still like to escapeshellarg() as appropriate.  Since the $data elements are already urlencoded, how should I apply escapeshellarg()?  Thanks

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,flatten_GP_array($data));

function flatten_GP_array(array $var,$prefix = false)
{
    //Used for CURL routines when sending multi-dimential array
    $return = array();
    foreach($var as $idx => $value){
        if(is_scalar($value)){
            if($prefix){$return[$prefix.'['.$idx.']'] = urlencode($value);}
            else {$return[$idx] = urlencode($value);}
        }
        else {$return = array_merge($return,library::flatten_GP_array($value,$prefix ? $prefix.'['.$idx.']' : $idx));}
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Even with hashing and escaping I would strongly advise not to do this.

Comment: @flu.  Why not?  My purpose for doing so is a fax server.  My web server sends some data to the fax server, and the fax server sends out a fax.  The fax software requires exec().  Now that I am writing this, I am asking myself whether a SOAP client/server would be better...

Comment: Because you're hashing your data I think that your fax server is publicly available and even though you're going to escape the parameters there's still a big injection risk. If possible define fixed parameters for your "protocol" and interperet them on side of your fax server. It's just I would never send any parameter directly to the shell, a database query or similar security relevant systems.

Comment: don't escape on the client for this. you ALWAYS escape on the server, just before you use the data in whatever context you need to do the escaping for. e.g. if you escape on the client, a malicious user will forge a request and send something un-escaped. boom goes your server. e.g. skip the entire escaping business on the client and do it purely server-side.

Comment: @flu.  Some of the parameters being sent are the message/name/etc, and they cannot be fixed.  The fax application takes this data and creates a fax coversheet and sends the fax.  The shell needs to initiate the fax application.  Since the parameters are suspect, they need to be appropriately escaped.  Maybe I can escapeshellarg() the already urlencoded data, or if un-ulrencodde the data?

Comment: @MarcB.  Agree about needing to always escape at the end.  Purpose of escaping on the webserver (which is actually a fax client for this given purpose) is only to allow multidimensional data to be based via cURL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to crypt your data with a very long encryption key which only your host and your server knows.

You can use [this encryption/decryption class (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2448441/601386) from John Conde.

For the sake of simplicity I would then simply serialize your `$data` array, crypt it and send it to your server.

```
$urlData = Encryption::encrypt(serialize($data));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array('data' => $urlData));
```

On side of your FAX server just decrypt the data and unserialize it again

```
$data = unserialize(Encryption::decrypt($dataParameterFromUrl));
```

Server-side you know have the exact same data you had on your client and can do whatever you want with it.

Furthermore you could use something like [challenge response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9934272/601386) to verify your host.

Comment: Thanks flu.  So at this point, you would consider the data secure and not use escapeshellarg()?

Comment: I always use it (if I have to invoke shell commands). But I also think that you need to use it because you stated you're going to sent the FAX message body as command line parameter too. If that's the case you have to escape them just to support quotes which would otherwise break your command line input. If possible write the body to a file and let the fax application read that file.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  Different question but would you use cURL or SOAP?

Comment: cURL is just a transfer library while SOAP is a protocol (whose implementation might use cURL). If you only have this scenario I would use cURL for simplicity.